# Showing Modal Fade in Angular not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to show a component "Login", which has a class "modal fade" from another component "navbar", but it's not working. I tried calling data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal" from "navbar", but that wouldn't change the state of the Login component.

Also, directory tree would look like components -> header_components -> navbar, while Login component is in components -> unregistered_components -> login. I'm not sure if that would make a difference when doing sth like this.

**Navbar**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal" style="cursor: pointer">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" >{{menuItems.at(-2)?.linkName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<app-login></app-login>
```

**AppLogin component**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="LoginModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
        <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular users Shadow-dom, which means - CSS styles from one component cannot be used in another component. Even if it is a child component.

You basically have 2 options..

1. Move the "modal fade" CSS classes in the global `style.scss`
2. (Not recommended) - Make the NavBar -> in `@Component` decorator change the  `encapsulation` ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)) to `ViewEncapsulation.None`

> This will make the component styles globally available.